# installing ubuntu 22 on dual boot caused a fatal error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had a laptop with dual boot. I had windows 10 and ubuntu 18.10 installed. I was trying to install ubuntu 22 in place of ubuntu 18.10 but while installing fatal error appeared. It said that it couldn't install grub. I tried to fix this with boot repair on Live ubuntu booted from pendrive but the program says : "Legacy Windows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to Legacy mode."
I have enabled legacy boot mode in my BIOS. Do you know how could I fix this?

Comment: Do not mix UEFI & BIOS on same drive & best not to on different drives of same system. Windows should be UEFI, unless you did not install it correctly. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. BIOS mode is more for very old hardware. But converting MBR to gpt will erase drive. You also have only one MBR, so grub will need to be in MBR, but if Windows turns fast start up back on or needs chkdsk, you have to restore a Windows boot loader. Make sure to have Windows & Ubuntu live installers or repair flash drives.

Comment: Be aware that Ubuntu Core 22 is a different system to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The *year* (20, 22) products are different, to the earlier 18.10 release you were using which was a *year.month* format (2018-October release or 18.10). The *year* products (22) are for *headless* server use only; where as the *year.month* (22.04) can be used as server or desktop systems.  I'd recommend 22.04 replacing 18.10, and not using Ubuntu Core 22 to replace it.